# STL container type as template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to create the generic class template that uses internally a specific container to determine the different types. Something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
template< typename F, template< class ... > class container_type = std::vector >
struct C
{
    C();
    template< typename U >
    C(container_type< U >);
    C(container_type< F >);
    C(container_type< int >);
    container_type< double > param;
};
C< unsigned, std::list > c;
```

What is the most natural way to do this? Say, whether you want to mention the presence of the container's allocator in any form?

Comment: I'd suggest that you're best not to do this. While the STL containers are _similar_ in interface they are, of necessity, not _identical_. Moreover, the most efficient way to work with one container is not necessarily going to be the most efficient way to work with another. I do not think it likely that you can successfully template out your storage without running into difficulties.

Why is it that you want to do this? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to have a choice between the speed of access to element, which allows vector, and speed of insertion, which provides a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

something like this?

```
template< typename F, template<class T, class = std::allocator<T> > class container_type = std::vector >
struct C
{
    C() {}
    template< typename U >
    C(container_type< U >) {}
    C(container_type< F >) {}
    C(container_type< int >) {}

    container_type< double > param;
};

C< unsigned, std::list > c;
```

**EDIT:**

Similar but a bit simpler approach is used by `std::queue` which is parametrized by the type of container which will be used internally. Hopefully this proves this approach is quite natural.
The sample above was tested in VC++10 and shows how to deal with an allocator.

Comment: @Dukales: see my edit. What alternatives do you mean? Your question doesn't include any info to guess this.

Comment: So we can use only
`(constructor)
empty
size
front
back
push
pop`
in this case? But what about the `<algorithm>`'s?

Comment: It does not solve the problem of `template< ... > struct C`'s parameters list inflating.

Comment: @Dukales: <algorithm> mainly uses iterators, so this should be fine as far as you use compatible iterators. As Jack Aidley said it his comment, STL containers are pretty incompatible, but there's still room for their interchangeability.

Comment: @Dukales: please elaborate why do you need `template< ... > struct C`. I cannot help you if you'll provide so limited info.

Comment: `std::queue` is only limits us and keeps in limited way.

Comment: Class `C` has different methods that work with the same fields (which would imply the use of a specific container): some of them work faster with one type of container, the other — with the other type of container (not necessarily from the `STL`, perhaps from the `boost::`, too).

Comment: I want to have a choice between the speed of access to element, which allows vector, and speed of insertion, which provides a list, in different instantiations of `C`.

Comment: @Dukales: OK, so what's the problem with this approach? It's not universal and you can imagine cases when it doesn't work well? No doubt, but it's how STL is designed and you cannot do anything with this. Implement specializations for couple of main containers to gain maximum speedup.

Comment: Thank you, you've done enough. I just wanted to analyse the problem as far as possible. Thank you again.